# How can I eliminate clipping of my font icon in IE11?

Tags: extjs

When run in IE11, this fiddle's title icon is flattened on the top and bottom:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1iam

When run in Chrome, the check box icon is completely round.  How do I change the css to eliminate the clipping in IE11?  I don't want to reduce the size of the icon, but that's the only effective way I've eliminated the flat edges on top and bottom.

Comment: Why not use the existing functionality to set a panel header icon, instead of nesting it all in the title as html?

Comment: Good question.  It's been a long time since I wrote that, but I think the reason was that I am sharing some of the css classes with other components, and I couldn't apply them in the same way to the header.  Don't hold me to that.